# Crash on master/detail app, when changing category, after releasing Var

Tags: ios, memory-management, ios4

I'm struggling to figure out why my app is crashing when I release synthesized properties. My app launches, and when I tap on a row, it takes me to DetailViewController, then when I go back and tap a row again the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

DetailViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UILabel *clipboardLabel;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *clipboardLabel;

@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize clipboardLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    clipboardLabel.text = @"Tap an image to copy";
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [clipboardLabel dealloc];    
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `release` instead of `dealloc` on your clipboardLabel in the `dealloc` method.

That should be :

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [clipboardLabel release];    
    [super dealloc];
}
```

A general rule : one should **never** call `dealloc`on another object.

Comment: @Luzal: Greedy much? He cannot accept it before a certain amount of time passes.

Comment: @PengOne: That's something I didn't know. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `dealloc`:

```
[clipboardLabel dealloc];    <-- Wrong
```

call release:

```
[clipboardLabel release];    <-- Right
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was having an end of day moment :)